# Where is the echo command file found

Tags: windows, command-line

If I type

```
where echo
```

it returns a message like :

> INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

Where is the `echo` command found?

Comment: It's a shell built-in like `echo` in bash (`type echo`). I don't think Windows has a separate `echo` utility as many unixes do (`/bin/echo`)

Comment: I understood that echo is an internal command part of the cmd program. I like Linux and I want to develop my own Windows commands you see.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Echo is not a program but a command, which is part of the cmd.exe file located in your c:\windows\system32.

Comment: I see, I marked your answer as good.

Comment: These are called *internal commands*.